# Links in Lightbox 2.6 descriptions using data-title

Tags: hyperlink, lightbox

Although I've noticed most problems with lightbox concern the question of how to put links in the descriptions, I haven't yet come across an answer to the problem I'm having.

I'm running version 2.6 and modified it to use the description from the attribute "data-title" instead of "title". This worked fine, as did putting links in the descriptions, the problem is that when I click on those links nothing happens. They react to hovering over them, the browser's status bar displays the address I'm linking to, right-clicking will bring up the correct context menu, only left-clicking will do nothing.

This is the code of the image:
`<a href="img.jpg" data-lightbox="album" data-title="&copy; &lt;a href='http://www.link.com' target='_blank'&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;"><img src="thumb.gif"></a>`

And here's the page in question: http://himmelsbach-dourveil.net/fotos There's a link in the first photo's description.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your version of lightbox.
Have a look at this PR : https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/pull/194